# Google analytics tracking code causing error "missing ; before statement"

Tags: javascript, html

I have setup a new google analytics accounts for a language translation site located on a subdomain.

How come I am getting this error on only one of the sites:

```
Error: missing ; before statement
Source File: http://fr.example.local/
Line: 346, Column: 87
Source Code:
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www')   '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

The strange this is that if you compare both the sites below you shall see that 99% of the HTML/JS is exactly the same (use same template files just a separate database).

Comment: It's not strange. The thing that is different is the GA code :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `+`:

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same error even though I have the + sign. It occurs when this script is on the same page as some other js includes, like there's a conflict between two of them. The error in Firebug says the error is in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js so there could be a conflict there.

Comment: My problem here was that I needed to do a full page refresh when linking from jQuery Mobile site to a new page that has its own javascript to be loaded. Use data-ajax="false" for your link. Also the Google Analytics code was inside the body tag, not sure if that mattered.